# Some problems running Mongodb like service

Tags: bash, mongodb, ubuntu, service, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to run Mongodb like service following this [scripts configuration](https://gist.github.com/alex-klepa/2171496). Then when i try to execute any of this commands:

```shell
service mongodb [start|stop|restart]
service mongoconf [start|stop|restart]
service mongos [start|stop|restart]
```

I got this problem.

```shell
vagrant@sandbox-dev:~$ service mongodb start
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.5" (uid=1000 pid=1296 comm="start mongodb ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

I'm using **ubuntu 12.04** on my Vagrant VM.

Thanks for any help..!!

Comment: did you try to `sudo` it, i.e. `sudo service mongodb [start|...]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add **sudo**

```
sudo service mongodb [start|stop|restart]
sudo service mongoconf [start|stop|restart]
sudo service mongos [start|stop|restart]
```